# Words counting problem

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

What is the number of words, which are made by shifting all lower case letters in the english alphabet and none of them contains any of the four subwords (null, one, two, three)?

Comment: How long can a word be?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "shifting lower case letters"? If you are trying to count the number of words made out of the 26 letters in the English alphabet without specifying a length then there are an infinite number and the question doesn't make all that much sense.

Comment: I think what is intended is that of the $26!$ permutations of all the letters, how many qualify.

Comment: Like @André, I think that *shifting all lower case letters* refers to permuting the alphabet.

Comment: the word length is 26

Answer (score 0):

Let us focus on a simpler example. Suppose, that we are not allowed only one subword, say, 'null'. Without that restriction, we can form $26^{26}$ words (assuming a word length of $26$ and that we are allowed repetitions).

However, we want to exclude the word 'null' from our list. Now, the word 'null' can appear in any one of the following positions at the start of the word, in the middle or towards the end. There are $23$ such possible places where the word 'null' can appear. For each one of the $23$ places, we can fill the remaining places in $26^{22}$ ways.

Thus, the number of words where the word 'null' appears is $23 . 26^{22}$. Therefore, the number of words where 'null' does not appear is: $26^{26} - 23 . 26^{22}$

Answer (score 0):

Count all, subtract those that contain the forbidden words. To count, e.g. the permutations that don't contain `one`, consider that as a "superletter" and count the possible words containing it. Need count those containing `twone`, and so on. Use the idea of inclusion-exclusion to exclude the forbidden ones.